# Excel xlookup with nonzero values from bottom to top in special scenario

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a 2 columns as follows:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 100 |
| 1.2 | 100 |
| 1.3 | 1 |
| 1.4 | 2 |
| 1.5 | 0 |
| 1.6 | 0 |

I would like to obtain the first non-zero value and look from bottom to top of column2.

I used Xloopup as follows that didn't work in this special scenario, I wanted to get 1.4 instead, I got 1.3 which is xlookup's actual behavior.

`=XLOOKUP(1,M$1:M$6,$A$1:$A$6,"NA",1,-1)`

I appreciate if you can give me another formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might look a bit hacky, but try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=TAKE(FILTER(A1:A6,B1:B6),-1)
```

- `FILTER(A1:A6,B1:B6)` - Will return only those rows in `A1:A6` where values in `B1:B6` are different to zero;
- `TAKE(<Step1>,-1)` - Returns 1st row from the bottom.

The benefit of this approach is that it will become easy to get, say, the nth to last non-zero from the bottom too:

```
=@TAKE(FILTER(A1:A6,B1:B6),-n)
```

Where `n` would then be your desired occurence from bottom up and `@` is the implicit intersection operator to assert we don't work with a spilled range and only return the top left cell of our possible array.

If for some reason, you'd like to reverse the logic and return the nth occurence from the *top* instead, you could then apply the following logic:

```
=@DROP(FILTER(A1:A6,B1:B6),n-1)
```

---

An `XLOOUP()` variation to get the 1st value from the bottom could look like:

```
=XLOOKUP(FALSE,B1:B6=0,A1:A6,,,-1)
```

Where you'd provide an array of values to check against for `XLOOKUP()` in the 2nd parameter. In this case you would like to check if the values `B1:B6` would be equal to zero.

Comment: This works surprisingly well. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Plus there is the more old-fashioned =LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>0),A:A)